# Segfault: Track down "invalid read" "free'd at"

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, exit

I'm working on a rather complex piece of software and once in a while it segfaults on exit. I tried to investigate the problem with valgrind, but the output I get does not tell me which of the numerous usages of `QString` is the problematic one.

I used valgrind with `--track-origins=yes`, but this also does not help to see which one it is.

```
==28264== Invalid read of size 4
==28264==    at 0x563B66: QBasicAtomicInt::deref() (qatomic_x86_64.h:133)
==28264==    by 0x563DC6: QString::~QString() (in build/output/bin/qgis)
==28264==    by 0x36F8A395E9: __cxa_finalize (cxa_finalize.c:55)
==28264==    by 0x5B94212: ??? (in build/output/lib/libqgis_core.so.2.1.0)
==28264==    by 0x36F860FB69: _dl_fini (dl-fini.c:253)
==28264==    by 0x36F8A39278: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:77)
==28264==    by 0x36F8A392C4: exit (exit.c:99)
==28264==    by 0x36F8A21B4B: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)
==28264==  Address 0x135b30b0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==28264==    at 0x4A074C4: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28264==    by 0x36C48C31F7: QString::free(QString::Data*) (qstring.cpp:1235)
==28264==    by 0x563DDC: QString::~QString() (in build/output/bin/qgis)
==28264==    by 0x36F8A39278: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:77)
==28264==    by 0x36F8A392C4: exit (exit.c:99)
==28264==    by 0x36F8A21B4B: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)
```

How can I find the problematic instance of QString? Or what else can I do to track down problems where "below main" cleans up?

Comment: conditional breakpoint on that line perhaps...

Comment: print out pointer addresses when allocating, along with some general flow output will likwly tell you which area of code allocated the pointer that was the issue.

Comment: Do you have static QStrings?

Comment: Making a testcase will do that for you. Basic debugging technique.

Comment: RichardPlunkett: Is your idea to recompile Qt with a modified QString constructor? Or can you think of an easier approach (Maybe a macro?)

FrankOsterfeld: There are a couple of static QStrings (and probably a bunch of static objects containing QStrings).

Comment: A macro or a template function should do the trick

Comment: I don't know, how a testcase will help me to figure out in which area of the code the problem is. The way I know testcases are rather that they ensure that this will not happen again, once I isoltated and solved the problem. Can you elaborate, how you would do this? Also concerning a macro or template function, I am not sure about the way they are thought to be used in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a very (very!) similar problem with one of my global QString's, but this only happened in Qt 5 (5.1.1), not in Qt 4 (4.8.5)... the way I solved it in the end was to run the application through gdb / ddd and let it crash to determine the offending symbol's name. After figuring this out, I simply made it a member of one of my QObject-derived classes (there was actually no reason for it to be global) and this fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer René. How exactly did you get the symbol name? As far as I can tell, the variable is already deleted by the time it crashes and I cannot determine a useful symbol name any more.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer... and I don't remember the details now, but I recall that 'ddd' indicated the object that was causing the crash "quite obviously" :).